Proof explanation of Lemma 5.3.14 from Tao's Analysis I (3rd edition)
I do not understand parts in bold in the proof of the lemma which follows. Help me understand them.

Lemma 5.3.14. Let $x$ be a non-zero real number. Then $x=$ $\operatorname{LIM}_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$ for some Cauchy sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which is bounded away from zero.


Proof. Since $x$ is real, we know that $x=\operatorname{LIM}_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$ for some Cauchy sequence $\left(b_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$. But we are not yet done, because we do not know that $b_n$ is bounded away from zero. On the other hand, we are given that $x \neq 0=\operatorname{LIM}_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$, which means that the sequence $\left(b_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is not equivalent to $(0)_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Thus the sequence $\left(b_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ cannot be eventually $\varepsilon$-close to $(0)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for every $\varepsilon>0$. Therefore we can find an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\left(b_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is not eventually $\varepsilon$-close to $(0)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.


Let us fix this $\varepsilon$. We know that $\left(b_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence, so it is eventually $\varepsilon$-steady. Moreover, it is eventually $\varepsilon / 2$-steady, since $\varepsilon / 2>0$. Thus there is an $N \geq 1$ such that $\left|b_n-b_m\right| \leq \varepsilon / 2$ for all $n, m \geq N$.


On the other hand, we cannot have $\left|b_n\right| \leq \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$, since this would imply that $\left(b_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is eventually $\varepsilon$-close to $(0)_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Thus there must be some $n_0 \geq N$ for which $\left|b_{n_0}\right|>\varepsilon$. Since we already know that $\left|b_{n_0}-b_n\right| \leq \varepsilon / 2$ for all $n \geq N$, we thus conclude from the triangle inequality (how?) that $\left|b_n\right| \geq \varepsilon / 2$ for all $n \geq N$.


This almost proves that $\left(b_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded away from zero. Actually, what it does is show that $\left(b_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is eventually bounded away from zero. But this is easily fixed, by defining a new sequence $a_n$, by setting $a_n:=\varepsilon / 2$ if $n<N$ and $a_n:=b_n$ if $n \geq N$. Since $b_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, it is not hard to verify that $a_n$ is also a Cauchy sequence which is equivalent to $b_n$ (because the two sequences are eventually the same), and so $x=\operatorname{LIM}_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$. And since $\left|b_n\right| \geq \varepsilon / 2$ for all $n \geq N$, we know that $\left|a_n\right| \geq \varepsilon / 2$ for all $n \geq 1$ (splitting into the two cases $n \geq N$ and $n<N$ separately). Thus we have a Cauchy sequence which is bounded away from zero (by $\varepsilon / 2$ instead of $\varepsilon$, but that's still OK since $\varepsilon / 2>0$ ), and which has $x$ as a formal limit, and so we are done.


$\epsilon <|b_{n_0}|\le |b_{n_0}-b_n|+|b_n|<\epsilon /2 +|b_n|$.

Since $(b_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, for any positive constant $\eta$, there is an $N>0$ such that for all $n,m\geq N$ the terms $b_n$ and $b_m$ are within distance $\eta$ of each other, that is, $|b_n-b_m|<\eta$.
If we pick $\eta= \epsilon/2$, where we know that $(b_n)$ is not $\epsilon$-close to $(0)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ (since $x=\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n \neq 0$), then there must be some $n_0\geq N$ which is further than distance $\epsilon$ from $0$, that is $|b_{n_0}|>\epsilon$. But we chose the tail $(b_n)_{n \geq N}$ to have the property that all of its terms are within $\epsilon/2$ of each other, but then by the triangle inequality we have, for any $n \geq N$
$$
|b_n|+|b_{n_0}-b_n|\geq |b_{n_0}|
$$
and thus
$$
|b_n|\geq |b_{n_0}|-|b_{n_0}-b_n| >\epsilon - \epsilon/2 = \epsilon/2
$$
(since $n_0$ and $n$ are both greater than $N$ and so are within distance $\epsilon/2$ of each other). Thus we have shown that the tail $(b_n)_{n \geq N}$ is bounded away from $0$ by $\epsilon/2$. Replacing $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ by this tail we obtain a Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$ (where $a_n = b_{N-1+n}$) which has limit $x$ and all of its terms are bounded away from $0$ by $\epsilon/2$ as required.
